# What are good warranty coverage options for a pre-owned Mac?

Tags: mac, hardware, applecare, warranty

I am really looking at getting a used Mac Pro, and there are a lot of good used machines out there that will meet my needs that are around $1500. I was wondering what options I can get to help cover the repair / replacement of a used Mac Pro in the rare event that something goes wrong with it? A lot of the machines I am looking at are used and not refurbished and are not eligible for AppleCare any more. What do you use to cover your pre-owned and somewhat pricey used Macs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was purchasing the used mac from a 3rd party vendor, that offered a basic 1 year warranty for no additional charge.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is probably to look for a third party insurance company that offers policies for used computers. I ran a Google search for "`third party insurance for used computers`" and come up with one example insurance company, [Safeware](http://www.safeware.com/).

Whether such a warranty or insurance policy is worth the cost depends on how much you acquired your used Mac for and how much you value "peace of mind", since these policies are likely to be expensive and come with fairly strict limitations in coverage.

Answer (score 2):

If they're no longer eligible for AppleCare, there is no warranty available. Period.

The closest I can think of would be to get a rider on your homeowners' or renters' insurance to cover the computer, but it would likely cover different events than a warranty would (more on the order of theft, probably not hardware faults).

Talk to your local Apple Genius, your local Apple Authorized Reseller, and your insurance agent, in that order.

Comment: The lack of a warranty from Apple doesn't preclude a third party offering a warranty. A computer repair company, for instance, may offer an option to pre-pay at the beginning of a time period and then be eligible for repairs needed during that time period.

Comment: @DanielL I'd never heard of that as an option. It's certainly preferable (for these purposes) to an insurance rider. Both of the other answers, including the accepted one, mention that possibility.